# Change the color of a button on a standard pop-up action

Tags: iphone, button, colors

I am using a standard pop up action in my iphone app (the pop up at the bottom of the screen). This has 2 buttons "ok" and "cancel". It seems the standard colour scheme is to have the top button red. I want to change this so the top button is green. I have been googling forever and can't find the solution. Any ideas would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can browse through ActionSheet ( I assume you use UIActionSheet class) subviews - like that:

```
NSArray* subViews = [aSheet subviews];
for (UIView* sView in subViews)
{
    ...
}
```

And change subviews properties there as you like.

You can also create UIActionSheet without any buttons at all:

```
UIActionSheet* aSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\n\n" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil  destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

And afterward create your own custom buttons and add them to the ActionSheet view. (put more \n to the title to enlarge Sheet height)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're referring to a UIActionSheet.  In a UIActionSheet, you can define a button that cancels the action and has a black background, a button that marks a destructive action and has a red background, and all other buttons which have white backgrounds.  Which option corresponds to which class of actions can be specified in the initialization of the UIActionSheet using `– initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:`.

The design of a UIActionSheet, including why you should only use these colors for your buttons, is explained in the [iPhone Human Interface Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/ModalViews/ModalViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH11-SW13).  I'd follow Apple's suggestions in this regard, as they will make your application easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIActionSheet *action = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@""
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" 
                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil,@"Mail",@"Facebook",@"Twitter",nil
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
NSArray *buttons = [action subviews];
```